# Video has no sound

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, video

We added a video into the audio/video webpart. The video plays but there is no sound. If we play the video directly from another location, it works with sound. Only in SharePoint there isn't a sound. Do we forget a setting for audio/video webparts on our SharePoint server?

Comment: Do you have the right codec? Have you tried to insert another video? How do you play the video (browser, program?, IE?)

Answer (score 1):

As Plexus mentioned, you have to check media player plugin for the browser.
you can try couple of different things to identify the problem.

- try to play video from differnt computer/pc
- how you adding the video, are you uploading to SharePoint then embed in media web part?
- Try to add the video into different site collection and test it.
- play the video in window media player on the pc.
- May be you need to update the window media player plugin for broswer.

Check the below post for more troublshooting options:

- [Technet post 1](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/e8cccea8-7282-435d-a0db-a71da87895d5/sharepoint-2010-no-audio-plays-with-media-web-part?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)
- [Technet post 2](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ceceff35-14c7-43c1-999b-0b174f649bad/media-player-web-part-gives-no-sound?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)